# Equivalent of scikit-learn's GroupShuffleSplit in dask-ml?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dask, panel-data, dask-ml

I'd like to split my data into testing and training sets, but I have repeated observations of people over time, so I'd like to do the splitting in a way that none of the people have observations that appear in both the test and training data sets. To do this kind of splitting in scikit-learn, I'd do something like this, using [GroupShuffleSplit](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#group-shuffle-split):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

X = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 2.2, 2.4, 2.3, 4.55, 5.8, 0.001])
y = np.array(["a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a"])
groups = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4])

gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
train, test = next(gss.split(X, y, groups=groups))

X_train, y_train = X[train], y[train]
X_test,  y_test  = X[test],  y[test]
```

How can I do this with Dask or Dask-ML?